# Iterating over list creates endless loop and extends list even though it should not

Tags: python, list

I iterate over a Sublist (A). A has a defined lenght. Then, i extend another list (B) with the values of (A). For some reason, the first sublist (A) gets extended by the value i extend the other list (B) by.

I have absolutly no idea why this would happen and I'd be very thankfull for help regarding this issue.

```
combinations_list = [[[[1, 0], [], -3], [[0, 2], [], -3], [[2, 1], [], -3], [[0, 3], [], -3]]]

for A in combinations_list:
    B = []

    for i in range(len(A)):
        for element in A[i][0]:

            if B == []:
                B.extend(A[i])

            else:
                if element in B[0]:
                    for e in A[i][0]: #Endless loop, A[i][0] gets extended by value of e
                        B[0].extend([e])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were appending a shallow copy of `A's` sublists into `B`. This means that when you were changing `B` in the last loop, you were actually also changing elements of `A`.. so `A` just kept growing and the loop kept iterating.

To avoid it, use `deepcopy` from the `copy` module - it creates an actual, independent copy of `A`s lists so now when you change them through `B`, only `B` will have them,

```
import copy

combinations_list = [[[[1, 0], [], -3], [[0, 2], [], -3], [[2, 1], [], -3], [[0, 3], [], -3]]]

for A in combinations_list:
    B = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for element in A[i][0]:
            print(B)
            if B == []:
                B.extend(copy.deepcopy(A[i]))
            else:
                if element in B[0]:
                    for e in A[i][0]:
                        B[0].append([e])
```

Answer (score 1):

After you do `B.extend(A[i])`, `B[0]` references the same list instance as `A[0][0]`.  So ,when you get to `B[0].extend([e])`, you're actually adding to `A[0][0]` as well.  The loop `for e in A[i][0]:` for the first `i` will never end because you are adding to A[0][0] at every iteration.